# Is it ok to go back and "cleanup" questions and answers that I've asked/answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

I've been looking though some of my questions and answers and realized that some of them are the highest quality that I want them to be at.  Is it bad protocol to go back and cleanup questions and answers to make them a higher quality?  For example a question with multiple edits/updates cleaned up to a single question, but with the same material.

[Here is one of my questions](https://superuser.com/questions/184868/system-critical-error-kernel-power-and-crash) as a reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it bad protocol to go back and cleanup questions and answers to make them a higher quality

No, that's actually a good thing.

---

The point of a continuously edited questions and answers site is that the people seeking the information can find it right away, without having to jump through hoops and pages long discussions. Consolidating and cleaning will help not only others who are seeking the same, it will help you in the future. 
(Yes I'm speaking from personal experience).

Comment: I've done this to some of my own answered questions.  It's a good team effort that keeps the site running smoothly for all.